# Trigger to update another table with sum of a column of original table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a Project table:
[image]

and a Milestone table:
[image]

Whenever any insert, update, delete is made to Milestone table, Project table needs to updated.

ProjectCost column in Project table is the sum of its milestones. Milestone table has ProjectId column which tells which Project does a milestone belong to.

Everytime any change is made to milestone table, ProductCost in Product table should be updated.

I'm having problem in the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER UpdateProject 
   ON  [Organisation].[dbo].[Milestone] 
   AFTER INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    UPDATE T1
    SET T1.ProjectCost = (SELECT SUM(MilestoneCost) FROM [Organisation].[dbo].[Milestone] T2 
                            WHERE T2.ProjectId=)
    FROM [Organisation].[dbo].[Project] T1
    INNER JOIN Inserted i ON T1.ProjectId=i.ProjectId
    WHERE T1.ProjectId=

END
GO
```

How should the trigger be?

**EDIT**

I edited the trigger as:

```
USE Organisation
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [UpdateProject]
   ON  [Organisation].[dbo].[Milestone] 
   AFTER INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    UPDATE T1
    SET T1.ProjectCost = (SELECT SUM(MilestoneCost) 
                            FROM [Organisation].[dbo].[Milestone] T2 
                            WHERE T2.ProjectId=i.ProjectId)
    FROM [Organisation].[dbo].[Project] T1
    INNER JOIN Inserted i ON T1.ProjectId=i.ProjectId
END
GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pretty close:

```
BEGIN
    UPDATE T1
        SET T1.ProjectCost = (SELECT SUM(MilestoneCost)
                              FROM [Organisation].[dbo].[Milestone] T2 
                              WHERE T2.ProjectId = i.ProjectId
                             )
    FROM [Organisation].[dbo].[Project] T1 INNER JOIN
         Inserted i
         ON T1.ProjectId = i.ProjectId;
END;
```

The `join` in the outer query and the correlation in the `where` does the filtering that you want.

Comment: I'm getting a error: Cannot create trigger on 'Organisation.dbo.Milestone' as the target is not in the current database.

Comment: @Engineer . . . Do `use Organization` before the `create trigger`.  SQL Server only allows you to create a trigger in the current database.  This is documented (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx).  I'm not sure what the reason is, perhaps to prevent ambiguity in the body about which database to use for referencing non-fully qualified objects.

Comment: Doesn't this ignore deletes?